# Updating a dictionary with integer keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a short assignment where I have to read in a .txt file and create a dictionary in which the keys are the number of words in a sentence and the values are the number of sentences of a particular length.  I've read in the file and determined the length of each sentence already, but I'm having troubles creating the dictionary.

I've already initialized the dictionary and am trying to update it (within a for loop that iterates over the sentences) using the following code:

```
for snt in sentences:
    words = snt.split(' ')
    sDict[len(words)]+=1
```

It gives me a KeyError on the very first iteration.  I'm sure it has to do with my syntax but I'm not sure how else to update an existing entry in the dictionary.

Comment: You really can't update a dictionary if the key whose value is being updated has not yet been created. Use `defauldict` from `collections` or use an `if-statement` to check if `len(words)` is a key in the dictionary.

Comment: To be complete, there is also the oft forgotten [```dict.get()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method ... ```sDict[len(words)] = sDict.get(len(words), 0) + 1```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdicts` were invented for this purpose:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sDict = defaultdict(int)
for snt in sentences:
    sDict[len(snt.split())] += 1
```

If you are restricted to the use of pure dictionaries in the context of your assignment, then you need to test for existence of the key before incrementing its value in order to prevent a `KeyError`:

```
sDict = {}
for snt in sentences:
    num_words = len(snt.split())
    if num_words in sDict:
        sDict[num_words] += 1
    else:
        sDict[num_words] = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize the dictionary, it starts out empty. The next thing you do is look up a key so that you can update its value, but that key doesn't exist yet, because the dictionary is empty. The smallest change to your code is probably to use the `get` dictionary method. Instead of this:

```
sDict[len(words)]+=1
```

Use this:

```
sDict[len(words)] = sDict.get(len(words), 0) + 1
```

The `get` method looks up a key, but if the key doesn't exist, you are given a default value. The default default value is `None`, and you can specify a different default value, which is the second argument, `0` in this case.

The better solution is probably `collections.Counter`, which handles the common use case of counting occurrences:

```
import collections
s = map(str.split, sentences)
sDict = collections.Counter(map(len, s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I ended up getting it to work using a defaultdict but it's good to know why it wasn't working.